# Run scheduler to execute a function where scheduler data and input for function stored in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scheduler

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'MarketId': ['1.170349308', '1.170349312', '1.170349315'],
        'CodeExection': ['17:14', '17:25', '18:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['MarketId', 'CodeExection'])
```

I would like to pass the '`MarketId'` row value to a function at the time in `'CodeExection'`.

I have tried the following:

```
def test(df):
   def test1(df):

     print(MarketId)

   schedule.every().tuesday.at('CodeExection').do(test1) 

   while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Though I get the following error:

```
NameError: ("name 'CodeExection' is not defined", 'occurred at index MarketId')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your current CodeExecution is variable, but you need the value in `data['CodeExecution']`

Answer (score 0):

You can slice a dataframe just like a list:

`market_id_vals = df["MarketId"]`

`code_exec_times = df["CodeExection"]`

You will receive a Series. If you want you can convert it easily to a list like this

`df["MarketId"].tolist()`

`df["CodeExection"].tolist()`